# Directory not published

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a little problem and I don't find any solutions.
In my asp.net web application, I have a directory in the solution with some xls files.

[image: ScreenShot]

When I make a publication, I hoped that the directory is in the source files rendered. But the directory isn't there and I have to copy/paste it manually.
The problem is that I forget to do it regularly. Can I tell to visual studio to add this directory to the sources?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the files in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Then in the Properties grid, set the build action to Content. This will copy the files to the build output.